# Custom Record Visualforce Page Override Standard Page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, related-list

We have an Opportunity that has a related lookup list to a custom object. When we click on the related list record it opens up a custom Visualforce page. Hopefully this is a simple oversight for me but I am confused how the related record knows to pop a VFP. There isn't anything on the header of the VFP that would indicate it was taking over the standard page layout of the custom record. How would a custom VFP override the standard layout of a custom object?

Comment: most likely, the standard View button was overridden for that custom object. See Setup | Buttons and Actions for the custom object

Comment: brilliant. thank you that was it

Answer (score 1):

When the standard detail page doesn't display when clicking on a link to that object, the most likely reason is that the standard View action has been overridden for that object (standard or custom)

You can see this in `Setup | Object Manager | _your object_ | Buttons and Links`

- In Classic - you can override with a visualforce page
- In Lightning, you can override with the Classic override (i.e. VFP) or with a Lightning component

here's an example from an org I have:
[image]